# Java многопоточность

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

В процессе написания программы на яве с использованием нитей столкнулся с проблемой.В программе запущено сразу 8 нитей. Каждая нить должна выводить на экран сообщения типа :

> 1 Андрей Снял со счёта 98 Cейчас на счёту: 4902

где первая цифра это :

```
private int id = 1;
```

и доступ к ней реализован через

```
public synchronized int idPlus() {
   return  id++;
}
public  synchronized int getId() {
    return id;
}
```

часть кода выполняемой нити:

```
bank.putOn(currsumm);
String s = getId() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Положил на счёт " + currsumm + " Cейчас на счёту: " + bank.getBalance();
System.out.println(s);              
idPlus();
```

Но когда запускаю программу переменная id с одинакомым значеним может выскочить несколько раз. И получается, что то вроде этого :

> 1 Борис Снял со счёта 106 Cейчас на счёту: 4751
>
> 1 Галя Снял со счёта 63 Cейчас на счёту: 4751
>
> 1 Валентин Снял со счёта 80 Cейчас на счёту: 4751
>
> 1 Андрей Положил на счёт 99 Cейчас на счёту: 4850

Уже объявлял переменную id volatile и вызывал у нитей join();
Что можете подсказать с по данной проблеме ?

Весь код : https://ideone.com/MygrDN

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы не совсем понимаете принципы многопоточности и методов синхронизации.
Если я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите сделать, то вам надо что-то такое:

```
bank.putOn(currsumm);
synchronized (this) {
    String s = getId() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Положил на счёт " + currsumm + " Cейчас на счёту: " + bank.getBalance();
    System.out.println(s);              
    idPlus();
}
```

И убрать `synchronized` из методов. НО! Это будет неправильное решение, потому что фактически программа превратиться в однопоточную, т.к. все операции будут идти последовательно в разных потоках, а не параллельно как вам бы наверное хотелось.

Для вас правильным решением было бы увеличивать значение ID прям в методе который возвращает это значение. И при этом использовать не `int`, а `Integer` чтобы возвращался новый объект, а не ссылка на тот, который может быть изменен из другого потока. Т.е. должно быть что-то такое:

```
private Integer id = 1;

public  synchronized Integer getId() {
    return id++;
}
```

Comment: Я не хочу убирать synchronized из методов, я хочу что бы каждый выведенный id был уникален. C заменой int на Integer ничего не поменялось. Или это просто невозможно если потоки будут идти параллельно друг другу ?

Comment: @Zawarudo idPlus вместо getId

Comment: Я в обоих методах  заменил int на Integer

Comment: @Zawarudo Надо не только заменить на Integer, надо сам метод получения Id поменять.

Comment: Да, сразу не заметил. Теперь все работает правильно, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Zawarudo тут идея в том, что Integer immutable класс. т.е. он не меняется, а создаётся новый объект и возвращается в поток, и получается, что у каждого потока свой объект независимый от остальных. В вашем же варианте вы возвращали ссылку на один и тот же объект, который все использовали получали одинаковые ID.

Comment: Видимо я неправильно понял synchronized, ибо считал, что все должно выглядеть так:
 1) Запуск потоков 
 2)Потоки работают и обращаются к методам 
 3) т.к. методы синхронизированы одновременно пользоваться ими может только один поток и получить свой уникальный id (кто успел тот и съел)

Comment: Специально возвращать `Integer` вместо `int` не нужно, т.к. в java возврат, как и передача параметров, осуществляется по значению, поэтому поменять после `int a = getId()` не обращаясь непосредственно к `a` нельзя. Для создания генератора уникальных идентификаторов лучше воспользоваться методом `incrementAndGet()` класса `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`, т.к. это стандартное решение, использующее [CAS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Comment: @zRrr Вы правы, что-то совсем из головы это вылетело) Притом правы, как в случае с `int`, так и в случае с `ID`. Но иногда полезно самому это сделать, чтобы понимать как это работает и уже в продакшене использовать какие-то стандартные решения, с пониманием как оно работает и что может случиться.

Answer (score 1):

Дело тут в том, что получение значения переменной id и ее увеличение - разные операции, и планировщик может приостановить поток в момент когда одна операция была выполнена а другая еще не началась. Блок synchronized тут не поможет.
В данной ситуации id нужно объявить как AtomicInteger. А строку формировать следующем образом :

```
       bank.putOn(currsumm);
       String s = id.incrementAndGet() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Положил на счёт " + currsumm + " Cейчас на счёту: " + bank.getBalance();
       System.out.println(s);
```